# NodeJS App with waiting for the admin to accept

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-admin, user-permissions

I'm trying to create a Full Stack App with the following requirements:

- Have users that post photos
- Have an admin that gets those photos and accepts/rejects the photo to be published

So, the user should be able to upload a photo, and, if the admin accepts, the photo should be rendered to the user screen. Otherwise, the user should get some kind of alert saying that the uploaded photo was rejected.

Do you guys know some kind of project where it was done so it can guide me? Or any advice on how to do it?

Comment: do you save db data for the uploaded photos?

Comment: I should save them, yes

Answer (score 0):

start with a register/login system first where the users will be given different roles ( admin and user). Then create an admin panel for the admin followed by a profile page for the user. Use a database to send the profile pictures to and display the data in the admin panel, where the admin has got the option to either reject or accept the data. if its accepted display the profile pic otherwise delete the data entry and send a message to the user who has uploaded the profile pic.

Comment: Another tip is to plan the project and write the code you want to implement in words (psuedocode as we call it) it gives a more clear vision on what to do and how to do it.